# Trying to add options to a datalist from a MySQL table, but the options aren't always displayed (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, electron

I am trying to add option elements to a datalist. I'm querying a MySQL server using node. I want to make it so that as long as the input the user types in is present at any point in the string of a name of a university, that university will be displayed as an option in the datalist. The querying works fine and everything, but the thing is is that when I add the options to the datalist they aren't always displayed. For example, when I type "Academy" I get the drop down list of university names including the word "Academy" (limited to a maximum of ten options):

[Searching for all universities with "Academy" in the name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKQKk.png)

But when I try entering "Academy Butler" no options are displayed even though there exist universities with names that include both words (that are successfully queried from the table):

[Searching for all universities with the words "Academy" and "Butler" in the name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmUde.png)

When I look at console.log() output, the valid universities of the "Academy Butler" search are printed out, meaning the query worked fine. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Here is my code:

register.js (Renderer Process):

```
let ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
let uniName = document.getElementById("uniName");
let dropdown = document.getElementById("uniList");

/**
* This thing just lets the main process (main.js) know about the event.
*/ 
uniName.addEventListener("input", () => {
    ipcRenderer.send("user_typing", uniName.value);
});

/**
* This adds the options to the datalist after getting the query result array in main.js.
*/
ipcRenderer.on("uni_list", function(event, uniList) {
    dropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Resetting the dropdown datalist so there aren't duplicate query results in the list.
      for (uni in uniList) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = uniList[uni].NAME;
        dropdown.appendChild(option);
      }
});
```

main.js (Main process):

```
const electron = require("electron");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const ipcMain = require("electron").ipcMain;

ipcMain.on("user_typing", function(event, nameValue) {
    let string = nameValue;
    let statement = 'SELECT NAME FROM all_universities WHERE MATCH (NAME) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);';
    connection.query(statement, string, function(error, result) {
        if(error) throw error;
        let small_list = [];
        if(result[0] != null) {
            for(let i=0; i<10; i++) { // Limiting possible options to 10 so as not to slow everything down with thousands of options.
                small_list.push(result[i]);
                console.log(small_list[i].NAME); // Outputting the names to see if they are being added to the array.
            }
        }
        event.reply("uni_list", small_list); // Sending the list of universities containing user input back to render process so the datalist can add them as options.
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_styles.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>University Registration</h1>
    <form>
       <label for="uniName"> University/Institution: </label><br>
       <input list = "uniList" name="uniName" id="uniName">
       <datalist id="uniList">
       </datalist> <br>
       <label for="password"> Create Password: </label><br>
       <input type="password" id="password"> <br>
       <label for="passwordConf"> Confirm Password: </label><br>
       <input type="password" id="passwordConf"><br><br>
    </form>
    <button id="submitButton"> Register </button>
    <script>
      require("./register.js");
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: datalists only display options that have values that so far match what the user input string is (or potentially could be). Example: if there is an option "Butler Acacdemy" and the user types in "Academy Butler" the option of "Butler Academy" would not be displayed. If the user typed in "Butler Aca", the option would be visible. So either I will have to make my own custom dropdown search bar or just use a select element.